# Why is filebeat creating a new datastream everyday?

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

A very simple filebeat

```yaml
filebeat:
  inputs:
  - type: filestream
    id: vouchers-logs-stream
    paths:
      - /path/to/logs/*.log
    json:
      keys_under_root: true
      add_error_key: true
      overwrite_keys: true
      message_key: message
    parsers:
      - ndjson:
          target: ""
          add_error_key: true
output:
  elasticsearch:
    hosts: [ "..." ]
    username: "..."
    password: "..."
    index: voucher-app-logs-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}
setup:
  template:
    name: "voucher-app-logs"
    pattern: "voucher-app-logs*"
    overwrite: false
  ilm:
    enabled: true
    policy_name: "voucher-app-logs-lifecycle-policy"
```

This configuration creates the following:

- A data stream called: voucher-app-logs-8.7.0-2023.04.19
- A index called
  .ds-voucher-app-logs-8.7.0-2023.04.19-2023.04.19-000001
- And at each day, a new datastream is created

My questions:

- Why create a new datastream everyday?
- How to change the name of the datastream?
- How to create only one datastream for these index patterns instead of
  creating one new ds every day?

I have read the docs and found nothing about that. Perhaps I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tldr;

Beats is doing what he is told to ^^

In the output section:

```yaml
output:
  elasticsearch:
    hosts: [ "..." ]
    username: "..."
    password: "..."
    index: voucher-app-logs-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
                                                 This will change every day
```

So everyday the beat is going to look for a datastream that does not exist yet. And will create one.

## Solution

Is removing the data an option for you ?

```yaml
output:
  elasticsearch:
    hosts: [ "..." ]
    username: "..."
    password: "..."
    index: voucher-app-logs-%{[agent.version]}
```

Comment: Didn't knew that the `index` property was intended to also affect the datastream name. I thought that this property was meant to affect the index name. Thank you!

Comment: Agreed, it is a bit confusing